# How to convert trigger into handler of after insert, after update, before delete

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

```
        trigger DPRLineItemsTrigger on DPR_Line_Items__c (after insert, after update, before delete) {
        if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore)
{Map<String, DPR_Line_Items__c> InstlineidDPRLI = new Map<String, DPR_Line_Items__c>();
            Map<String, DPR_Line_Items__c> InstlineidDPR = new Map<String, DPR_Line_Items__c>();
for(DPR_Line_Items__c olddprLineItem : trigger.old){
                InstlineidDPRLI.put(olddprLineItem.Installation_Line_Items_ID__c, olddprLineItem);   
                InstlineidDPR.put(olddprLineItem.DPR__c, olddprLineItem);   
            }for(DPR__c ili : [SELECT Id, Cable_Tray_Installation_Manhours__c FROM DPR__c WHERE Id =: InstlineidDPR.keySet()]){
                    system.debug('InstlineidDPRLI.get(ili.id): '+ InstlineidDPR.get(ili.id));
                    DPR_Line_Items__c iDPR=InstlineidDPR.get(ili.id);
                    if(iDPR.Installation_Activity__c == 'Raceway and Junction Box'){
                    DPR__c eachInsta = ili;
                    eachInsta.Raceway_JB_Installation_Manhours__c= eachInsta.Raceway_JB_Installation_Manhours__c- (iDPR.Number_Of_hours__c * iDPR.Number_Of_Labours__c);
                    // eachInsta.Total_installed_quantity_DPR_Quantity__c = eachInsta.Total_installed_quantity_DPR_Quantity__c - iDPR.Daily_Measure_Quantity__c;
                    update ili;
                    }
            }
for(Installation_Line_Items__c ili : [SELECT Id, Manhours__c, Total_installed_quantity_DPR_Quantity__c FROM Installation_Line_Items__c WHERE Id =: InstlineidDPRLI.keySet()]){
                system.debug('InstlineidDPRLI.get(ili.id): '+ InstlineidDPRLI.get(ili.id));
                DPR_Line_Items__c iDPR=InstlineidDPRLI.get(ili.id);
                Installation_Line_Items__c eachInsta = ili;
                eachInsta.Manhours__c = eachInsta.Manhours__c - (iDPR.Number_Of_hours__c * iDPR.Number_Of_Labours__c);
                eachInsta.Total_installed_quantity_DPR_Quantity__c = eachInsta.Total_installed_quantity_DPR_Quantity__c - iDPR.Daily_Measure_Quantity__c;
                update ili;
            }
}
if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert){
            List<DPR_Line_Items__c> dprLineItem = [SELECT Id, Installation_Activity__c, Number_Of_hours__c, Number_Of_Labours__c, DPR__c FROM DPR_Line_Items__c WHERE Id in :trigger.new];
            System.debug('DPR_Line_Items__c => ' + dprLineItem);
            for(DPR_Line_Items__c dprli : dprLineItem) {
                System.debug('dprli => ' + dprli);
                List<DPR__c> dpr = [SELECT Id,
                                    Raceway_JB_Installation_Manhours__c,
                                    Conduit_Installation_Manhours__c,
                                    FROM DPR__c WHERE Id =: dprli.DPR__c LIMIT 1];
                System.debug('dpr => ' + dpr);
                DPR__c updatedpr = dpr[0];
    if(dprli.Installation_Activity__c == 'Raceway and Junction Box'){
                    updatedpr.Raceway_JB_Installation_Manhours__c = updatedpr.Raceway_JB_Installation_Manhours__c + dprli.Number_Of_hours__c * dprli.Number_Of_Labours__c;
                    update dpr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [Edit] your question to add that information. At its most simple, this is just a copy/paste job. The stuff in the before insert block => copy/paste into a "public void beforeInsert(<params>)" method, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this pattern:

```
trigger DPRLineItemsTrigger on DPR_Line_Items__c (
    after insert,
    after update,
    before delete
) {
    new DPRLineItemsHandler.handle(
        Trigger.operationType,
        Trigger.oldMap,
        Trigger.newMap
    );
}
```

with the handler:

```
public inherited sharing class DPRLineItemsHandler {

    public void handle(
        TriggerOperation op,
        Map<Id, DPR_Line_Items__c> oldMap,
        Map<Id, DPR_Line_Items__c> newMap
    ) {
        switch on op {
            when AFTER_INSERT, AFTER_UPDATE {
                ...
            }
            when BEFORE_DELETE {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [Get Started with Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) for a broader discussion.

Note that:

- The query `FROM DPR_Line_Items__c` isn't needed because those values are already available in the `Trigger` context
- The two queries `FROM DPR__c` inside a loop will cause a governor limit to be hit when there are many `DPR_Line_Items__c`s involved so those queries should be moved to outside the loops by gathering the Id values and querying once into a `Map<Id, DPR__c>`.
- Consistently indenting your code will make it easier to read and so make problems easier to find.